# Can’t change AppStore country/region

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore

I recently relocated from India to Japan. I need to install a Japanese banking app, but the iPhone is not letting me change my country/region.

I’ve tried changing the country under settings -> AppleID —> Média and Puchases, but the changes are not getting saved and the Manage Payments tab is still pulling in my Indian credit card information.

When I try to change the credit card in App Store, the iPhone is showing the country as Japan but making me choose one of Indian states.

Grateful if someone could help me out.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try going to https://appleid.apple.com/#!&page=signin and login with your Apple ID. Next, select “Account” and scroll to the bottom. If the “COUNTRY / REGION” box is grayed out, ensure that…

- Your Apple ID Balance is empty
- You have no active Subscriptions
- You have no active Memberships, Pre-orders, Movie rentals, or Season Passes, and no pending Store Credit or Refunds to process. You can cancel a pre-order if you need to.
- Make sure you have a payment a method(s) for your new location.

You can also change your region (On iOS) by entering Settings —> YOUR NAME —> Media & Purchases —> View Account —> Country/Region.

If this doesn’t work, please comment below!

Comment: I have done this already but it's not resolving the problem :-(

Comment: You can confirm that there is absolutely no money in your account, or any subscriptions, etc? If you have cards in Wallet, I would remove those, and maybe add a card for the new country. If you are still stuck, you may need to ask Apple Support. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your having been able to change your Apple ID's country/region but not being able to remove your old credit card and add a new one implies the problem is on Apple's side. The suggestions outlined in another reply here are necessary for changing an Apple ID's country as listed in this [Apple Support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201389) but you seem to have already changed your Apple ID's country. So none of these is likely to be the underlying problem. I suggest you contact [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/contact).